# Insert between and after with regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm trying to find solution to insert all images in html code in a div.

At the moment they are stored as strings in MySQL database like this

```
Some text <img src="link" alt="">
```

I want to replace all these images with `<div class="bilde"><img src="link" alt=""></div>`

I tried

```
function bilde($saturs) {
  preg_replace('<img(.*?)>', '<div class="bilde"><img$1></div>', $saturs);
}
```

and many other solutions, but regex is not really my strong side.

Comment: Are you wanting to update all the strings that are stored in the database?

Comment: no, i just want to edit output, insert images in div that formate them with css.

Comment: Fair enough. My idea of posting a MySQL command won't help you then! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using regex delimiters. Try this code:

```
preg_replace('/<img(.*?)>/is', '<div class="bilde"><img$1></div>', $saturs);
```

I added `i` (ignore case) and `s` (DOTALL) to make your regex more useful.

However remember that Using regex is not always the best way to parse HTML.

Comment: it does the same, nothing is in output, and also no error code.

Comment: You need to use return value of `preg_replace`.

Comment: thanks, i added echo to my function, and now it works, but it don't echo in correct order. in code echoing title is first and echoing text is after it, but it prints out text and title then.

Comment: @user2454075, what do you mean ? the code above works like a charm... Are you sure you're forgetting nothing ? Check [this demo](http://codepad.org/1z2Ll1T4) using a function

Comment: yes, code above works perfectly fine.
but somehow my function prints text before the the title, which in code is printed out before text

oh, my mistake was not returning anything. thanks! everything now works fine.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.